# Mojo complex dependency injection

Tags: maven, plugins, dependency-injection, parameters, mojo

I'm trying to use the `@Parameter` above a field in a mojo.

```
@Parameter(required = false)
public Map authentication;
```

In plugin usage I'm passing:

```
<configuration>
   <authentication>
       <user>a</user>
       <server>
           <address>server.com</address>
           <port>123</port>
       </server>
   <authentication>
</configuration>
```

The behaviour is that maven seems cannot inject all data, just the `<K,V>` that is simple, like `<user>` that has a `String` but in case of `<server>` I'm expecting the same behaviour, for instance, another `Map<K,V>` with `<address>` and `<port>`, but maven injecting `null`

Comment: you have read https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#Maps ?

Comment: Yes, I have read it but no information about complex arbitrary configurations is informed, just as the example, with no more than a level of depth

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at the [Mapping Complex Objects](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Complex_Objects) documentations.

If I understand you correctly, you want to configure a setting for an "authentication", but have its values be arbitrary key-values, where values might be some complex object "server" and have its "address" and "port" mapped into the correct type?

It's probably a good idea to not model this as a Map, but have some object representing this structure

```java
public final class Server {
    private String address;
    private Integer port;
    // getters 
}

public final class Authentication {
    private String user;
    private Server server;
    // getters 
}

public final class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter
    private Authentication authentication;
}
```

This allowes you to use the snippet configuration that you provided.

If I understood incorrectly, and you *actually* want a `java.util.Map<K, V>`, where you can provide the authentication with arbitrary values, you might be out of luck. I guess you could make the `Authentication` class hold a Map for extra things:

```java
public final class Authentication {
    public String user;
    public Server server;
    public Map<String, String> other;
}


...
<properties>
  <authentication>
    <user>theUser</user>
    <server>
      <address>server.com</address>
      <port>123</port>
    </server>
    <other>
      <key1>value1</key1>
      <key2>value2</key2>
    </other>
</properties>
...
```

My personal advice would be to go with the route of explicitly modelling the structure you want to have. This allows you to let the Maven-plugin environment to do as much checking for you as possible. If you take an arbitrary map, then you have to do all sorts of marshalling yourself.

One downside is that Maven does not provide a nice descriptor for complex objects, but you won't have that with a plain Map anyway.